# Why 'sequentialfs' of MATLAB stops before the optimum feature subset is selected?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, matlab

I am using "sequentialfs" of MATLAB to select features from 271 features for 871 subjects over 2 classes. I used the backward sequential function. I noticed the features selected after using the algorithm isn't the optimal feature subset. Because, if I re-run the algorithm on the previously selected features, then more features are removed from the feature set and it also increases the classification accuracy. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

`obs=Features;     %These are the 271 features
grp=LABELS;       %Label of the features (Two classes only)

c = cvpartition(grp,'k',10);
opts = statset('display','iter');

fun = @(xtrain,ytrain,xtest,ytest) sum(ytest ~=predict(fitcdiscr(xtrain,ytrain),xtest));   %Criterion

[fs,history]  = sequentialfs(fun,obs,grp,'cv',c,'options',opts, 'direction','backward');  %Calling the backward sequential feature selection`